# opengl widget library for ios

Tags: c++, ios, ipad, opengl-es

I'am trying to build an iphone/ipad app with a custom ui. Something like this:
 [image: this]
<sub>(source: [korg.com](http://www.korg.com/Uploads/ProductThumbnails/1iMS20_180_634245498851210000.gif))</sub>

I believe this kind of interface heavily relies on opengl.
 My question is: is there any library with the kind of widgets in the picture (knobs, sliders, cables, etc)?
If there isn't, is there any library that helps with the construction of such widgets? I'am looking for this so I do not have to implement myself the whole widget hierarchy and the opengl event handling.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any particular reason that the above interface must be written with GL/ES. You should get pretty far with Quartz / UIKit (unless there is another reason to use GL).

If you are looking for standard widgets such as buttons, the built-in ones offer pretty good customization with state images.

The widgets in your example are highly specialized, and unless you are able to find some "synth widget set" you are probably going to have to write your own widget set (as for the knobs, look at the built-in [gesture recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html), they should be able to do the trick).

Regardless of if you decide to go with OpenGL or use Quartz, the difficult part will probably be capturing and responding to user interaction, rather than rendering of the widgets (which I assume will rely on static images being changed, moved and/or rotated). My advice would be to search for an implementation of, or ask a specific question about, the specific widget you want to build in this case.

> I'am looking for this so I do not have to implement myself the whole widget hierarchy and the opengl event handling.

Regarding this, I just want to point out that there is no need to use "opengl event handling" (not sure what it means), but you can use the same event handling as any other widget, including gesture recognizers.

Comment: I believe this is opengl because of the smoothness while performing real time synthesis.

Comment: If you are talking about display performance, either approach will take advantage of graphics hardware (high performance while low on CPU usage). OpenGL will clearly perform better (and likely be the only viable option) when you want to render complex scenes.

Comment: With opengl event handling i'am referring to the use of techniques such as ray picking to identify wich object is being used. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: That is used when creating 3D interactive scenes. It would help knowing what you are trying to do. The given example is a standard 2D user interface (although with some custom widget types).

Comment: Yeah, it's a 2d user interface, but there has to be some sort of picking to detect touches in a drop down list for example (you have to detect that the interaction was with the list and not with what's underneath it). Maybe there's some simpler approach...

Comment: Again, I believe that you should stick to the cocoa apis if this is the only thing you want to do, and even if you don't, look into gesture recognizers!